# Convet array of binary digits to a decimal using array.reduce method

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary, reduce

I am trying to use array.reduce on an array representing a single binary value. For instance [1,0,1] in binary would convert to 5 in decimal.

I have been able to succesfully convert between binary and decimal using a while loop, but would like to *upgrade* my code to use the reduce method.

What I have implemented so far is accurate up to 6 elements in the array. I am not sure why, but after 6 digts, the conversion fails.

In addition, I am using a formula to make the conversion. For example: to convert 111001 to decimal, you would have to do (1*2^5) + (1*2^4) (1*2^3) + (0*2^2) + (0*2^1) + (1*2^0).

```js
const getDecimalValue = function (head) {

     let total = head.reduce(
         (sum) =>
         sum + (head.shift() * Math.pow(2, head.length))
     )
     return total
}

console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 0, 1]) == 5)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]) == 57)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]) == 115)
console.log(getDecimalValue([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 7392)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 18880)
```

This was my code using the while loop

```
    let sum = 0
    while ((i = head.shift()) !== undefined) {
        sum += (i * Math.pow(2, head.length))
        console.log(i * Math.pow(2, head.length))
    }
    return sum
```

Comment: You are mutating the array as you're iterating over it. Just...don't do that, since you're making the whole operation work wrong after you shift out the indeces.

Comment: I wish all questions asked here were so clear in scope and came with their own tests.  +1 for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutating the array as `reduce` is iterating over it. This changes the array underneath, so the operation gets out of sync with the underlying values. Here is a (somewhat loose) illustration of how `reduce` normally walks the array:

```
arr =       [1, 2, 3]
             ^  ^  ^
             |  |  |
iteration 1 --  |  |
iteration 2 -----  |
iteration 3 --------
```

Here is what happens when you modify it each iteration:

```
//start
arr =       [1, 2, 3]

//at iteration 1
            [2, 3] _
             ^
             |
iteration 1 --

//at iteration 2
            [3] _ _
                ^
                |
iteration 2 -----

//at iteration 3
            [] _ _
                 ^
                 |
iteration 3 ------
```

Instead, the straight forward way to get your functionality is to make each item a power of 2 that is equal to the *reverse index* of the item

```
//index:            0   1   2   3
arr =              [1,  0,  1,  0]
//reverse index:    3   2   1   0
```

And conveniently, to get that, you simply need to subtract `1` from the array length (because indeces are 0-based and length = 1 only has index = 0) and then subtract the normal index. This gives you the powers of two each value represents:

```
//reverse index:    3   2   1   0
arr =              [1,  0,  1,  0]
//power of 2:       8   4   2   1
//multiply and sum: 8 + 0 + 2 + 0 = 10
```

And here is the code using `reduce`:

```js
const getDecimalValue = function (head) {

     let total = head.reduce(
         (sum, item, index, array) =>
        sum + item * Math.pow(2, (array.length - index - 1)),
// reverse index                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        0
     )
     
     return total
}

console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 0, 1]) == 5)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]) == 57)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]) == 115)
console.log(getDecimalValue([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 7392)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 18880)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was very close to what you suggested in my original attempts. I appreciate the clear and succinct explanation

Answer (score 4):

You could reduce the array and multiply last value and add the actual value.

```js
const getDecimalValue = array => array.reduce((r, v) => r * 2 + v, 0);

console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 0, 1]) == 5)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]) == 57)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]) == 115)
console.log(getDecimalValue([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 7392)
console.log(getDecimalValue([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) == 18880)
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it way more readable using the following function with [Array.prototype.reduceRight()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight).

```js
function binaryToDecimal(arr) {
  let decimal = 0;
  arr.reduceRight((base, binaryNum) => {
    if (binaryNum === 1) {
      decimal += base;
    }
    base = base * 2;
    return base;
  }, 1);
  return decimal;
}

binaryToDecimal([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])===3462
```